# Remove element from array with reference

Tags: php, arrays, reference, element

I have an array containing multiple objects of class `X`, some of them having exactly the same values.

I also have a reference (let's name it `R`) to one of the objects (of class `X`) in this array.

Is it possible to remove the object referenced by `R` from the array, without removing the other same objects than the one `R` references to?

Comment: Have you any code to share to make your question / problem clearer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For object `$a` and `$b` of class X:

if `$a = &$b`, `$a === $b` returns true.

if `$a = clone $b`, `$a === $b` returns false.

So here comes the O(n^2) algorithm:

```
$obj_array = array(/* ... */);

$keys = array_keys($obj_array);

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($keys); ++$i) {
    $duplicate = false;
    for($j = 0; $j < $i; ++$j) {
        if(!empty($obj_array[$keys[$j]]) && $obj_array[$keys[$i]] === $obj_array[$keys[$j]])) {
            $duplicate = true;
        }
    }
    if($duplicate) {
        unset($obj_array[$keys[i]]);
    }
}
```